# Is it OK to say: We suggest you instead to something do?

Tags: grammar

The person told to the company that he uses the machine in the evening. Is it ok to answer:
We suggest you instead to use this machine in the morning after your breakfast.

Comment: We don't say *"we suggest you to"*; we say *"we suggest that you"*.

Comment: ...also, you don't "tell to Sb.", you just _tell them_; also "suggest to use" is wrong. : ..and "and that he use(s)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the expression might be valid, it is not commonly used.

You could say:

> We suggest that you use this machine in the morning after breakfast instead of the evening